# Composer doesn't recognize git despite it being in the system PATH

Tags: windows, git, composer-php

I'm using the latest version of Composer on a Windows 2016 Server. When I run...

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev drupal8 --no-dev --no-progress --stability dev --no-interaction
```

from an admin command prompt, it gives the error:

"git was not found"

However, a regular command prompt recognizes git and both paths are in my system PATH.

```
C:\Users\username>git --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1
```

and

```
C:\Users\username>where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran the same Composer command using the already installed Git Bash application and it worked.

Git Bash can be found in the Windows/Application menu.